# How do i set a background image for a division with an image already in it?

Tags: html, css

I've ran out of hope for this for the past few days,what I'm basically trying to do is to do this:

CSS:

```
.div1{
/* background-image code */
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="div1">
<!--Image here-->
</div>
```

Is it even possible to have a background image larger than the image in the div itself?

Comment: You could put the image, which you want to be smaller, inside another div in div1. And then make the new divs size according to what you want.

Answer (score 1):

See the following example to achieve what you are looking for. Basically you can combine a color and an image by using both the `background-color` and `background-image` props at the same time. Position and scale the image with `background-size` and `background-position`. `background-repeat: no-repeat;` is important to be able to see the area that is the simple color background.

```css
.div1 {
  background-color: blue;
  background-image: url(https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/b/forrest-27720334.jpg);
  background-size: 50%;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;

}
```

```html
<div class="div1">
</div>
```

For two images layered in this way:

```css
.div1 {
  background-image: url(https://www.realtree.com/sites/default/files/styles/site_xl/public/content/inserts/2022/imagebybarriebird-ducklings.jpg);
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
  color: white;
  background-size: 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  /*to center the text */
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.div1::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url(https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/b/forrest-27720334.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  /*to set this image layer behind the duck one */
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="div1">
  Example content text
</div>
```

Comment: Hey there,this did help me a bit,but for the colored part i was going to add another image in there as the background,any insight on how to achieve so?

Comment: See edit. I added a second example

Answer (score 0):

you can add width and height in each img and background-image

```css
.div1{
    width: 100vw;
    height: 500px;
/* background-image code */
}

img {
   width : 200px;
   height : 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="div1">
    <img src="code.png" alt="">
    <!--Image here-->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give the img some padding and put the background image on it.

```css
div {
  width: fit-content;
}

img {
  background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/id/1015/300/300);
  background-size: cover;
  padding: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1016/200/300">
</div>
```